# Как вставить на web страницу тег так чтобы он не работал, но его видел пользователь?

Tags: html

Начал изучать html и решил заодно создать сайт на котором я буду конспектировать свои знания. 
Хочу вставлять теги и т.д. в качестве примеров, но браузер их читает. 
Как сделать так что бы он их не читал, но клиент на той стороне их видел?

Comment: добавить display: none;

Comment: <pre> или <code>

Comment: 1) Использовать HTML-entities: `&lt;div&gt;...&lt;/div&gt;`; 2) вставлять динамически через JS: `element.textContent = '<div>...</div>'`

Comment: @Yaant спасибо!